# Reading words from a text file C++ (weird characters)

Tags: c++, file, text

```
firstword secondword thirdword fourthword ...
```

My text file contains 200 words like this order and I want to read and copy them into a 2D fixed length of array, without weird characters. I couldn't be able to perform this operation with this piece of code:

```
ifstream FRUITS;
FRUITS.open("FRUITS.TXT");


    if(FRUITS.is_open())
    {
        char fruits1[200][LEN];
        int c;

        for(c = 0; c < 200; c++)
        {
            char* word;
            word = new char[LEN];

            FRUITS >> word;

            for(int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
            {
                fruits1[c][i] = word[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: 'Weird characters' is very descriptive.

Comment: You've mentioned what your code doesn't do.  What **does** it do?

Comment: Does `LEN` the length of the longest word + 1?

Comment: Are you sure your file name is correct? Is it TXT or txt?

Comment: `char word[LEN]` would be an improvement over your memory leaks.

Comment: For example, when a word's length is less than LEN, the rest of the word array aside from the actual word contains characters like "=+½$#". I don't want to print those.

Comment: @burakongun and those characters `=+½$#` **do print** when you try to print the values?

Comment: @burakongun Please show the code that prints these values and the complete output you get.  This code is okay.  Your printing code may not be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `'\0'` at the end of the word so there won't be any wierd characters if the length of the word is less than `LEN`.

However I recommend using vector of strings for the job.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    fstream file;
    vector<string> v;
    file.open("FRUITS.txt");
    string tmp;
    while(!file.eof())
    {
        file >> tmp;
        v.push_back(tmp);
    }
    for(vector<string>::iterator i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); i++)
    {
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `FRUITS >> word;` should add the `'\0'`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Well yes it does. Then maybe he is printing the array not like strings but like chars or something... He`s not giving us the code that outputs the array.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this:

```
FRUITS >> fruits1[c];
```

But you have to be sure that `LEN` is sufficient to hold all the `char` in each word plus the `'\0'`.

And don’t worry about the `"=+½$#".` When you do thing like `cout << fruits1[c];` they don’t get printed.